# creating set of stopwords in nltk python

Tags: python, nlp, nltk, stop-words

I know that NLTk stop words has a lot of languages but what if I want to create my own set of stop words and want to use them in NLTK stop words is that doable ?

```
import nltk
from nltk.corpus import stopwords
stops=set(stopwords.words('My own set'))
words=["Don't", 'hesitate','to','ask','questions']
print([word for word in words if word not in stops])
```

Comment: define it as `stops = ("your","stop","words")` and use it in your code

Comment: I think putting it as an a array will make the program very slow specially for NLP and big set of  data is there a way to do it as a set ?

Comment: `stops` is set only

Comment: do you have a solution to import it form a txt file or an csv file ?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Store the set of stop words with space as dilimiter in a text file such as stop.txt

`stop_words = open('stop.txt','r').read().split()`

This would return the list with stop words in it.

Answer (score 2):

An altnerative or perhaps a lower cost way is to create a FILENAME.py file with the stopwords as a list. Then import FILENAME.py and call the stopwords list. This will eliminate I/O.

Comment: If you have a StopWordsFile.py for example and it contains a list of stopwordslist = ['they', 'she', 'he', 'we']. Then on the other file you import it, ie. from StopWordsFile import stopwordslist